# Regarding new version of andriodx in andriod studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-camera-intent, android-intentservice

I am using new version of andriox studio but i am getting some errors while i am running the project, error occurs in ContenetMainbuilding.java file
Note: i am using Firebase and fragment as well
**
import androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout;
^
symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
location: package androidx.constraintlayout
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwKqa.png)**

Answer (score 0):

You shoule use

> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

instead of `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: doesnt   work any other solution ?

Comment: afther running the project it automatically goes to the same "androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayoutt" layout  and shows the same error ,  other solution ?

Comment: Also, you can enable auto-import by going to `File` - `Settings` - `Editor` - `General` - `Auto Import` and tick on **Add unambigious imports on the fly** & **Optimize imports on the fly** in both Java and Kotlin sections. This will avoid you from mistyping imports.

Comment: @HASHMAT try add these to your `build.gradle`:
```dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3"
    // To use constraintlayout in compose
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0"
}```

Comment: i already added this but does not work in my case .

Comment: try going to `File` - `Invalidate Caches`, tick on optional and keep going. It's the last resort I can think of. Good luck : )